# save video currentTime in localStorage and video load() not working inside function

Tags: javascript

```
close.addEventListener('click',function(){    
  
    localStorage.setItem('time',video.currentTime);

    video.pause();
    video.removeAttribute('src');
    video.load();
});
```

I need to save currentTime into localstorage onclick close button, code works great and saves currentTime without "video.load();" function but when i use load() function then current time inside localStorage is always 0

main question: how to use load() function in my code and also save correct video `currentTime` inside localStorage?

Comment: you are only setting the `localStorage` item. Where is your code in which you are `getItem` from `localStorage` as well?

Comment: thanks for your response, getItem works correct i only need set correct item inside localstorage when using load() function

Comment: Any reason - Why are you using `.load` function inside your `close` function when setting the localStorage with `currentTime` ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping because after pause and remove src atribute load function is fastest way to disable downloading video data

Comment: I am trying to understand on whats the acutal issue here then ? you are using `setItem` and `getItem` - what is your having trouble with ?

Comment: when i use load function then set item is not working

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal working example with demo video and complete code to debug this issue further ?